# Open file in external storage through intent

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need a way to, when provided a path to a file, said file is open (I already have the user permission to manage all files). The code that got me closer to what I want is this:

```
val sfile: String = "/document/primary:11796018.pdf"
        val uri = Uri.parse(sfile)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.setType("application/pdf")
        intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open file"))
```

The screen to choose a app to open said pdf appears, but nothing happens, any help on what is the problem?

My android manifest looks like this:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

and the "file_paths" like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: "The screen to choose a app to open said pdf appears, but nothing happens, any help on what is the problem?" -- `sFile` is not a valid `Uri`. It appears to be a fragment of a `content` `Uri` that you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or something. However, you are missing the rest of the `Uri`. And, unless you took steps when you used `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` earlier, you will have no rights to access that document anymore.

Comment: @CommonsWare but if the user allow the app to manage all files I still need to have right over the file? Also, side question: can my app already have the pdf files and open those files with a line of code? (Like, the pdf are inside the app files)

Comment: "but if the user allow the app to manage all files I still need to have right over the file?" -- for that, you would use filesystem APIs. `/document/primary:11796018.pdf` is not a filesystem path. You got that presumably by parsing a `Uri` that you got from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, and that is not going to work. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is only tangentially related to the filesystem, and the `Uri` that you get back is much more reminiscent of a Web URL. If you hold `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, use `File` and `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, like in the old days.

Comment: I wonder why you posted that FileProvider stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, figured it out:

My file happens to be located on the download folder, so I had to add this line of code:

```
       val pdfFileName = "example.pdf"

        val pdfFile = File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
            pdfFileName
        )

        if (pdfFile.exists()) {
            val path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", pdfFile);
            val pdfIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf")
            pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
            pdfIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            try {
                startActivity(pdfIntent)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                // If there is no PDF reader installed, prompt the user to install one
                // Handle the exception as needed
            }
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the PDF file doesn't exist
        }
```

Also I have permission to manage all files, you can get this permission

```
val uri = Uri.parse("package:com.example.qrcodekotlin")
    startActivity(
        Intent(
            Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION,
            uri
        )
    )
```